# Flex transient dto stop collectionChanged event custom ComboBox

Tags: apache-flex, dto, itemrenderer, transient

I am having an issue with the `collectionChanged` event being fired when a `transient` property of a DTO is changed. I have a custom `ComboBox`, which has a `CheckBox` `itemRenderer` for each row, that stays open till the user moves focus away from it. The `dataProvider` is an `ArrayCollection` of `FooDto`. I want to be able to toggle the `visible` propery of the `FooDto`, but stop the `ComboBox` from closing due to the `dataProvider` being altered.

```
[Bindable]
class FooDto {
  public var id:int;
  public var name:String;
  [transient]public var visible:Boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Transient] metadata is to prevent a property from being serialized when you send it to a server. It will not prevent a property from being bindable.

I would suggest that you create a method setVisible() instead of using a property. If you then set a private variable, this will not trigger a collection change. You could also make each property in FooDto bindable except the "visible" property.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the [Bindable] before the class definition.

Comment: Ok, so I should make `visible` private and mutate it through get/set. Thanks.